# Preventing ALTER TABLE on PostgreSQL 9.4 even by the owner

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

We're using PostgreSQL 9.4.

We need to prevent users from doing an ALTER on a table, **not even the owner of the table**.

The owner of the table would have to 'grant' himself the permission to do the ALTER.

I imagine it would be like setting a 'read only flag' on the table's schema.

The table in question is being inherited from another table, if this has any importance.

The ideal solution would allow to do a message like "You can't ALTER the table because .... "

Is this achievable? and if so, how?

Comment: Maybe an [Event Trigger](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/event-trigger-definition.html) that throws an error?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name this might actually be perfect! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not what you actually want, but a potentially interesting effect:

When creating an inherited table, you have to do it as the owner of the parent table, but you can then change the owner of the child table. The new owner won't be able to drop/modify the inherited set of columns, though will still be able to change defaults/checks/triggers/etc, and to add new columns.

The simplest way to do something close to what you actually want is probably to control access by the owner role: create a separate role to access the tables, and revoke the CONNECT privilege on the database from the owner.